# Drag a "nephew" draggable to an "aunt" droppable while maintaining CSS and dimensions

Tags: jquery, css, css-position, jquery-ui-draggable

I want to drag a draggable `#red`, *nested* within some parent, to some droppable `#green`, which sits a level higher in the div structure.

The dimensions of the `div`s need to be expressed in `percent` (to be responsive), and the toplevel `div`s must be `position: relative;`, which might make things more complicated.

For comparison, this all works fine for a the simpler case, where draggable `#blue` and droppable `#green` are sibling elements, but breaks in the "nephew" scenario (`#red` on `#green`).

I understand that I need to:

- *`helper: clone`* the nephew (`#red`) div, as well as to `appendTo: "body",` so that I the nephew element can "escape"
- I also get that I need to append some styles (especially `position: relative;`) to `.ui-draggable-dragging`, so that the nephew element's dimensions are calculated with reference to the parent, while in transit.

So far so good.

One wrinkle remains: **When the nephew is dragged, it jumps sideways, and can't ever be dropped**.

What's going on here?

```js
  $(function() {
    $("#blue").draggable({
      snap: ".hexagon",
      snapMode: "inner",
      snapTolerance: 20,
      opacity: 0.7,
      addClasses: true,
      // stack: ".item",
      revert: "invalid"
    });
    $("#red").draggable({
      snap: ".hexagon",
      snapMode: "inner",
      snapTolerance: 20,
      opacity: 0.7,
      addClasses: true,
      // stack: ".item",
      revert: "invalid",
      appendTo: "body",
      helper: "clone",
    });
    $("#green").droppable({
      accept: ".hexagon",
      tolerance: "fit",
      drop: function(event, ui) {
        $(this)
          .addClass("ui-state-highlight")
          .find("span")
          .html("Dropped!");
      }
    });
  });
```

```css
.hexagon {
    width: 20%;
    padding-top: 25%;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 100% 25%, 100% 75%, 50% 100%, 0 75%, 0 25%);
    clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 100% 25%, 100% 75%, 50% 100%, 0 75%, 0 25%);
    -webkit-shape-outside: polygon(50% 0, 100% 25%, 100% 75%, 50% 100%, 0 75%, 0 25%);
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
  }

  .outer {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
  }

  .inner {
    background-color: red;
    z-index: 9999;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
  }

  .textstyle {
    color: white;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    top: 25%;
    left: 10%;
    right: 10%;
    bottom: 10%;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 1vw;
  }

  .green {
    background-color: green;
    z-index: 1000;
  }

  .blue {
    background-color: blue;
  }

  .red {
    background-color: red;
  }

  .ui-draggable-dragging {
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 25%;
    width: 20%;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="green" class="hexagon outer green">
    <span class="textstyle">
            I am the dropzone.
          </span>
  </div>
  <div id="blue" class="hexagon outer blue">
    <span class="textstyle">
            I drag just fine, because I'm just a sibling element.
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="hexagon outer">
    <div id="red" class="hexagon inner red">
      <span class="textstyle">
            I am nested, and I make a mess when dragged.
            I am the nephew.
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Why do you want to set `draggable` to the child of the red hexagon, instead of directly to the hexagon itself like you did on the blue hex?

Comment: My actual use case is a *grid* of `outer` hexagons (= **cells**), into which `inner` hexagons (= **items**) are placed. So the business logic seemed to suggest to me to nest the **items** inside the **cells**.

More to the point, in my use case, I need to be able to easily programmatically place (lots) of inner hexagons (such as `#red`) "*on*" (lots of) outer hexagons (such as `#green`).

Does that make sense?

Actual use case is here, FYI: https://maxheld83.shinyapps.io/sort/
(Here, draggables are *not* nested, precisely because of this problem, though they'd need to be).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Why does the clone jump?

It appears that the jQuery draggable plugin is adding a `left` value to the clone on the proviso that it is being positioned absolutely, by forcing `.ui-draggable-dragging`  to `position: relative;` the plugin is actually positioning the clone left relative to where the element was positioned initially on the page.

To fix this behaviour add an override to the clone to position it absolutely:

```
.red.ui-draggable-dragging {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: auto;
}
```

Additionally, add `bottom: auto;` to override the `bottom` value set by `.inner` as this will cause the clone to stretch.

### Why can't the clone be dropped?

This is because of `tolerance: "fit"` which according to the documentation:

> `"fit"`: Draggable overlaps the droppable entirely.

*Droppable Widget - (https://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#option-tolerance)*

This still causes problems now that the clone is positioned absolutely as it's `width` is not calculated to be the same as the original `.hexagon` (the original's `width: 20%;` is calculated against the `body` width while the clone's `width: 20%;` is calculated against the viewport). To mitigate this the default browser `margin` on the `body` has been suppressed (although this could also be solved by wrapping the `.hexagon`s in a container).

If the dragging action does not need to be exact `tolerance: "fit"` can be changed to `tolerance: "intersect"` which will allow for a bit more leeway.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#blue").draggable({
    snap: ".hexagon",
    snapMode: "inner",
    snapTolerance: 20,
    opacity: 0.7,
    addClasses: true,
    // stack: ".item",
    revert: "invalid"
  });
  $("#red").draggable({
    snap: ".hexagon",
    snapMode: "inner",
    snapTolerance: 20,
    opacity: 0.7,
    addClasses: true,
    // stack: ".item",
    revert: "invalid",
    appendTo: "body",
    helper: "clone"
  });
  $("#green").droppable({
    accept: ".hexagon",
    tolerance: "fit",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      $(this)
        .addClass("ui-state-highlight")
        .find("span")
        .html("Dropped!");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.hexagon {
  width: 20%;
  padding-top: 25%;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 100% 25%, 100% 75%, 50% 100%, 0 75%, 0 25%);
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 100% 25%, 100% 75%, 50% 100%, 0 75%, 0 25%);
  -webkit-shape-outside: polygon(50% 0, 100% 25%, 100% 75%, 50% 100%, 0 75%, 0 25%);
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.outer {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}

.inner {
  background-color: red;
  z-index: 9999;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.textstyle {
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  top: 25%;
  left: 10%;
  right: 10%;
  bottom: 10%;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 1vw;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.ui-draggable-dragging {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 25%;
  width: 20%;
}

.red.ui-draggable-dragging {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="green" class="hexagon outer green">
  <span class="textstyle">
            I am the dropzone.
          </span>
</div>
<div id="blue" class="hexagon outer blue">
  <span class="textstyle">
            I drag just fine, because I'm just a sibling element.
    </span>
</div>
<div class="hexagon outer">
  <div id="red" class="hexagon inner red">
    <span class="textstyle">
            I am nested, and I make a mess when dragged.
            I am the nephew.
      </span>
  </div>
</div>
```